# How can I avoid a forest of apostrophes?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Using Python 3.7, I have this confusing-looking, nested dictionary:

```
dict = \
    {
    'HBL_Posts':
        {'vNames':[ 'id_no', 'display_msg_no', 'thread', 'headline', 'category', 'author',
                    'auth_addr', 'author_pic_line', 'postbody',
                    'last_msg_no', 'mf_lnk', 'subject_header' ],
        'data_fname':'_Posts_plain.htm', 'tpl_fname':'_Posts_tpl.htm', 'addrs_fname':'_addrs.csv' },
    'MOTM':
        {'vNames':[ 'work_month', 'zoom', 'zoom_id', 'headline', 'description', 'subject_header' ],
        'data_fname':'_Posts_plain.htm', 'tpl_fname':'_Posts_tpl.htm', 'addrs_fname':'_addrs.csv'},
    'MOTM recording':
        {'vNames':[ 'topic', 'description', 'wDate', 'box', 'chat'],
        'data_fname':'_Recording_data.htm', 'tpl_fname':'_Recording_tpl.htm', 'addrs_fname':'_addrs.csv'},
    'Enticement':
        {'vNames':[ 'enticing_post', 'headline', 'hb_preface', 'postscript'],
        'data_fname':'_Entice_data.htm', 'tpl_fname':'_Entice_tpl.htm', 'addrs_fname':'_entice.csv'}
    }
```

If I initially set each variable to its own name, like: HBL_Posts = 'HBL_Posts', I can substitute this, much clearer and less typo-prone, code:

```
dict = \
    {
    HBL_Posts:
        {vNames:[ id_no, display_msg_no, thread, headline, category, author,
                    auth_addr, author_pic_line, postbody,
                    last_msg_no, mf_lnk, subject_header ],
        data_fname:_Posts_plain.htm, tpl_fname:_Posts_tpl.htm, addrs_fname:_addrs.csv },
    MOTM:
        {vNames:[ work_month, zoom, zoom_id, headline, description, subject_header ],
        data_fname:_Posts_plain.htm, tpl_fname:_Posts_tpl.htm, addrs_fname:_addrs.csv},
    MOTM recording:
        {vNames:[ topic, description, wDate, box, chat],
        data_fname:_Recording_data.htm, tpl_fname:_Recording_tpl.htm, addrs_fname:_addrs.csv},
    Enticement:
        {vNames:[ enticing_post, headline, hb_preface, postscript],
        data_fname:_Entice_data.htm, tpl_fname:_Entice_tpl.htm, addrs_fname:_entice.csv}
    }
```

In fact I accomplished this by just doing all the required assignments, one at a time. But that is about as complicated as the original dictionary set up, with the apostrophes. What I'd like is a function that would enable me to do this neatly and economically.

```
def self_name(s):
  [?????]
```

Then I could have a list of all the variables, vars_lst, and loop through it setting each to the literal version of itself:

```
for item in vars_lst:
  item = self_name(item)
```

To avoid having to use apostrophes in setting up vars_lst, I would accept doing:

```
HBL_Posts = vNames = id_no = . . . = ''
```

After many, many hours of struggle, I have been unable to supply the needed code for the self_name function. How can I do that, or how can I find another way of avoiding so many apostrophes?

Comment: Have you considered using `mydict = dict(keyword=value)` instead of initializing as `mydict = {'keyword': value}`?

Comment: "much clearer and less typo-prone". I disagree very much.

Comment: In general, I'd also recommend to break it down and define each sub-dict individually.

Comment: Having quotes isn't that confusing. The confusing part is the structure and the way it's presented. Use `json.dumps` with `indent` to make it look easy.

Comment: Have you considered defining it in yaml and then converting it to a proper python dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Indent it like JSON:

```
{
  "HBL_Posts": {
    "vNames": [
      "id_no",
      "display_msg_no",
      "thread",
      "headline",
      "category",
      "author",
      "auth_addr",
      "author_pic_line",
      "postbody",
      "last_msg_no",
      "mf_lnk",
      "subject_header"
    ],
    "data_fname": "_Posts_plain.htm",
    "tpl_fname": "_Posts_tpl.htm",
    "addrs_fname": "_addrs.csv"
  },
  "MOTM": {
    "vNames": [
      "work_month",
      "zoom",
      "zoom_id",
      "headline",
      "description",
      "subject_header"
    ],
    "data_fname": "_Posts_plain.htm",
    "tpl_fname": "_Posts_tpl.htm",
    "addrs_fname": "_addrs.csv"
  },
  "MOTM recording": {
    "vNames": [
      "topic",
      "description",
      "wDate",
      "box",
      "chat"
    ],
    "data_fname": "_Recording_data.htm",
    "tpl_fname": "_Recording_tpl.htm",
    "addrs_fname": "_addrs.csv"
  },
  "Enticement": {
    "vNames": [
      "enticing_post",
      "headline",
      "hb_preface",
      "postscript"
    ],
    "data_fname": "_Entice_data.htm",
    "tpl_fname": "_Entice_tpl.htm",
    "addrs_fname": "_entice.csv"
  }
}
```

or even store that in a `.json` file and load it via:

```
import json
with open('my_file.json', 'r') as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)
```

JSON is easy for most people to read and the indentation is easy to see. Plus it is easy to save and read from a file so you don't have to clutter your code.

FYI:

You can pretty print a dictionary using:

```
import json
my_dict = ...
print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4))
```

which is how I printed your dictionary.

Comment: All of these ideas are good ones. I particularly like getting the monster out of the program file into a json file that is imported. But I never heard of the possibility of doing something like mydict = dict{keyword=value}. I don't know how that could work, but I'll play around with it until I do.

Comment: Okay, I give up what did Daniel Lenz mean by: "using mydict = dict(keyword=value) instead of initializing as mydict = {'keyword': value}"???
When I try to do anything resembling dict(keyword=value) I get "TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable." I don't know what not being callable means, but more importantly, I don't see any options in how I initialize the dictionary.

Comment: He meant you can do `d = dict(a=2, b=3)`. That being said I don't recommend that direction.

Comment: As the kid says to "Mr. Science" in the old Bob & Ray routine, "Gee, I understand that even worse." How can a dictionary be set up with parentheses? I'm guessing you first do something like dict = {} and set up something in dict that d then creates a tuple for. But the syntax makes no sense to me. I tried just entering d = dict(a=2, b=3) and the interpreter rejected the syntax.

Comment: And no one, apparently, thinks it's possible to have a general way to do what the OP was about: set an object's value to be the same as its name. (E.g., myvar = 'myvar')

Comment: The code I pasted and you reiterated is valid syntax in Python3. A dictionaries constructor can convert key word arguments (`**kwargs`) into a dictionary, note I used keyword arguments in the constructor by using `=`: `(a=2)`. IDK what error your getting but if I had to guess you overwrote the `dict` object by doing something like `dict = ...`. Which if you don't understand the issue in using built in types as variables names you have a lot of other issues

Comment: "How can a dictionary be set up with parentheses?" Those "parentheses" are refered to as a constructor and can do lots of things it the background. It can return an empty dictionary, take a list of two element tuples and turn it into a dict, or even take keyword arguments and turn it into a dict. Be careful what you say or you may make yourself sound, for lack of a better word, stupid. Though it is understandable to not understand some of this advanced stuff (especially kwargs), you should choose a better tone when asking others for help, they will be more willing to walk you through it.

Comment: 1. Syntactical Remorse is correct on both counts: the code he posted is valid and I did not know that "dict" is a built-in type (so I have used it as the name of a variable or object--will fix). 2. I guess my introducing humor (Bob & Ray) didn't come across as the self-deprecation it was intended to, but apparently struck SR as arrogant. Thanks to him for explaining it despite that.